# .Net 5 - Asp.Net still has no SynchronizationContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-5

I would like to know if .Net 5 based ASP.Net applications still has no SynchronizationContexts [as mentioned here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/#ive-heard-configureawaitfalse-is-no-longer-necessary-in-net-core-true) so I can continue to not write `ConfigureAwait(false)` or should I start sprinkling it all over?

Comment: thank you. Could you can post that as answer? so I can accept it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, ASP.NET does not have a sync-context any more, and is *extremely* unlikely to ever regain one without a huge fight. You could verify this yourself by testing whether `SynchronizationContext.Current` has a value.

That said, if you're writing application level code, if there *was* a sync-context, you probably shouldn't be suppressing it; only library code should usually suppress sync-context, and library code should probably *not make assumptions about the host environment*, meaning: in library code you should probably add `ConfigureAwait(false)` manually if you don't want sync-context.